# передача большого объекта в iframe

Tags: reactjs, iframe, express

Есть React Component в котором загружается iframe.
src iframe ссылается на сервер, которому необходимо передать тяжелый object.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

class Frame extends Component {

  render() {

    const object = {
      id: 1,
      data: {
        id: 1
        data2: [{a: 1}, {b: 2}, {c: 3}]
        ......
      }
    }

    const url = `/html?object=${object}`;

    return <div>
      <iframe src={url}></iframe>
    </div>;
  }
}
```

Как передать такой большой объект чтобы на сервере его можно было получить например в виде reg.query (express) и распарсить снова в объект?

Comment: ну как вариант сделать отдельный post запрос и отправить json

Comment: Сериализовать объект, засунуть это все в base64. И передать строку как get параметр.
На сервере раскодировать строку, и расcирилизовать объект обратно.